# normalizing results from the graph or fql.query

Tags: facebook-graph-api, multidimensional-array, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I'm running an application that calls both the graph and fql.query for Insights information. (It happens to impersonate dozens of apps and pulls stats) I get a couple different formats back when querying and I'm wondering if there's a better way to 'normalize' results?

It would be nice to have something like this in the SDK, since Facebook formats/ data changes all the time. Where do I make an SDK request?

Code to get key-value--- 
[code]

```
public function saveResults($application = null, $result = array()) 
{
// graph insights are under a data key 
if(isset($result['data'])) {
    $this->saveResults($application, $result['data']);
}
// graph insights are under a values array  
elseif(isset($result['values'])) { 
    foreach($result['values'] as $k => $v) {
        $this->saveResult($application, $result['name'], $v['value'], $result['period'], $v['end_time']); 
    }
}
// fql.query results have a metric and value
elseif(isset($result['metric'])) {
    $this->saveResult($application, $result['metric'], $result['value'], $result['period'], $result['end_time']); 
}
// otherwise save key values 
elseif(is_array($result)) { 
    foreach($result as $key => $val) {
        if(is_numeric($key) && is_array($val)) {
            $this->saveResults($application, $val);
        }
        else {
            $this->saveResult($application, $key, $val); 
        }
    }
}
}
```

[/code]

Results from fql --

```
=> Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [app_id] => 1248...
                    [api_key] => 1248...
                    [canvas_name] => ABC123
                    [display_name] => ABC123
                    [company_name] => 
                    [developers] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [restriction_info] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [daily_active_users] => 0
                    [weekly_active_users] => 0
                    [monthly_active_users] => 8
                )

        )
=> Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [metric] => application_canvas_views
                    [value] => 0
                    [period] => 86400
                    [end_time] => 1317538800
                )

        )
```

Results from graph --

```
 => Array
        (
            [id] => 1248...
            [name] => ABC123
            [picture] => https://fbcdn-profile...
            [link] => http://www.facebook.com/ABC123
            [likes] => 58450
            [category] => Product/service
            [website] => http://www.ABC123..

 => Array
        (
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => ABC123.../insights/page_like_adds/day
                            [name] => page_like_adds
                            [period] => day
                            [values] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [value] => 60
                                            [end_time] => 2011-01-01T08:00:00+0000
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [value] => 15
                                            [end_time] => 2011-01-02T08:00:00+0000
                                        )

                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [value] => 2
```

Answer (score 0):

From my experience there's no 1:1 correlation between "object properties" being returned from the FQL tables to that of the new graph API objects.  There's so many more properties on the FQL tables than there are in the graph from what I've seen.  Trying to get them tied together would be like giving a cat a bath.  It can be done, but it's going to be painful!!

My suggestions would be to determine from the project requirements what you're trying to accomplish and then determine whether FQL or Graph API is your best route to getting to each requirement.  One requirement might be easier done with the graph, and another using FQL.  Good luck.